# Upgrade RAM beyond manufacturer's tested capacity?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade, compatibility

I seek to upgrade RAM from 12 to 64GB for deep learning, but remain uncertain about compatibility; this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-check-if-a-particular-RAM-is-compatible-with-a-motherboard-in-a-laptop-before-buying) thread suggests all's good as long as key specs of the new RAM match that of current RAM, whereas a manufacturer rep. informs my system's been "tested to work" with up to 32GB. Further, a [Crucial test](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/gl702vsk#MEMORYFilters) recommends only up to 32GB - but vast majority of its recommendations are its own products, so unsure about credibility there.

Below are my system specs vs. Crucial's 32GB recommendation specs vs. the seeked RAM's specs. All considered, is it 'unsafe' to upgrade to 64GB against manufacturer certification?

---

**SYSTEM**: ASUS ROG Strix [GL702VSK](https://amzn.to/2TAedUh), 12GB DDR4 2.4-MHz 1.2V (2 slots), [i7-7700HQ 2.8 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)

**32GB** [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/gl702vsk/CT10044835): --DDR4 2.4-MHz PC4-19200, CL-17, 1.2V, Dual Ranked
  **64GB** [Mushkin](https://amzn.to/2ke7a8a): DDR4 2.4-MHz PC4-21300, CL-19, 1.2V, Dual Channel, SDRAM

Comment: Unsafe? No. Guaranteed to work? No. Unless ASUS tech support tells you it can recognize a 32GB module, I advise against spending cash money on buying any.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Did you try to install the 64gb memory? I'm asking, because the CPU itself supports 64GB. At the time of manufacturing there were no 32GB modules so 2x16 was the maximum. Now with 32GB modules I'm wondering if it can support 2x32.

Comment: @KamenStoykov Haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whereas a manufacturer rep. informs my system's been "tested to work" with up to 32GB.

Your system absolutely does not support 32 GB modules which is the only way you could install 64 GB DDR4 in your system.  32 GB DDR4 module support does exist on 7th Generation Intel hardware it barely exists with 9th Generation Intel hardware.

> All considered, is it 'unsafe' to upgrade to 64GB against manufacturer certification?

Safety isn’t a legitimate concern in a case like this.  Your system will absolutely not recognize 32 GB DDR4 modules.

Comment: "7th gen Intel hardware" - meaning the CPU? I presume an i9 would support it, then? Either way, thanks for the info

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - I looked up your laptop, and the device I found was a 7th Generation Intel Core device.  You indicated your device has an i7-7700HQ processor not an i9 which only exists for the 8th and 9th Intel Core Generation processors. Besides, 32 GB DDR4 module support is determined by the motherboard, not the processor.

Comment: "Generations" of Intel CPUs are shown in the first place of the model number _after_ the hyphen. An i7-7700HQ is 7th Generation; see https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html whereas an i9-8950HK is 8th Gen https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134903/intel-core-i9-8950hk-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz.html

Comment: @K7AAY How misleading on behalf of Intel - I had no idea; good to know

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - They advertise and specify the generation on all their products.  They don't purposefully mislead anyone, just because you didn't know, does not mean they mislead you.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The first digit (after the _i_) in an Intel CPU name differentiates between i3, i5, i7, and i9 designs. It's not misleading at all, as they are very different. Here's a good explanation of the difference, as well as details on the rest of their naming system: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/intel-core-i3-vs-i5-vs-i7-one-really-need/

Comment: @K7AAY Let's just say it's consumer-unfriendly - as in nearly all non-technical literature, the main differentiator between types of CPUs is the *generation* - hence it'd make sense to have it lead the name, rather than denote a more involved definition. It's akin to code naming practices - make things easier, not harder. Anyway, knowledge acquired - thanks for sharing

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - AMD product codes are just as consumer-unfriendly as Intels.  Just because you were unware that an i9 product was not a 9th Generation Core processor does not mean the product name was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It's not dangerous, but it just likely won't work, if it's not within the spec supported by the hardware. Asus lists the [maximum ram as 32Gb](https://www.asus.com/uk/Laptops/ROG-GL702VS/specifications/) so you'll find it likely won't show anymore than this even if you put more in.

This is why Crucial also only recommend 32Gb. Occasionally there is hardware which supports higher values than shown on the spec sheets, but this isn't usual and unless you know someone who's tested it with higher there's little chance it's going to work.

Also as pointed out in